# Refraction of mechanical waves

Tags: waves, refraction

Everyone knows about the refraction of light. But what about refraction of mechanical waves?

With a quick research I was able to find that sound waves and water waves do undergo refraction. But I am unable to reach a conclusion for string waves.
I do know that string waves change their velocity on entering a different medium and the velocity of string wave in a medium is a characteristic property of the medium.

So does the transmitted string wave's velocity change due to refraction, or is it something else?

Comment: Earthquakes generate mechanical waves that diffract as they pass across the boundary between the core and mantle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refraction occurs across a change of medium because of the different velocities of the wave propagation in the two mediums.

As you say "string waves change their velocity on entering a different medium" then they will experience refraction.

Actually, its the change of propagation speed that is fundamental here and not the change of medium. Mirages occur in a desert because how the sun heats the desert air changes its refractive index in different layers. There is no change of medium here.

Comment: Can the propagation speed of wave  change due to some other phenomena?

Comment: @Vp127: Changing pressure.

Answer (score 0):

When I think of refraction I think of a wave changing direction at the boundary between two media. Elementary examples are light moving from air to glass, or water to air or something.

But for something to "change direction" it must be moving in at least two dimensions.

A string wave can only move forwards or backwards so it can't really changet the angle that it is travelling in.

So I would say that, while waves change their behavior in string waves as a result of differing velocities, it is impossible for a string wave (longitudinal or transverse) to exhibit refraction because it is a 1D wave.